# How to use Moment.js with ui.grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to convert all the dates rendered on Angularjs UI grid with countdowns. The dates are all in this format 01/19/2018 21:30 (Short US), Instead I want it to be xx Hour xx minutes left.

I have been trying with JavaScript and custom cell classes but I can't get it to work. I never worked with moment.js before but it seems that it might solve my issue, any ideas how I can run it inside of ui.grid?
this is what I have in columnDefs

```
{ field: 'DueDate', cellFilter: 'date:"short"'}
```

Edit :
Based on the answers bellow I am trying to alter the dates as soon as they come from hhtpget and replace them by countdowns

```js
$http.get("xxx/json").then(function(response) { response.data.forEach( function(row, index) { row.MakerDueDate = moment("row.MakerDueDate").countdown().toString(); }); $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data; });
```

Unfortunately this returns :

> TypeError: moment(...).countdown is not a function

I included moment.js, countdown.js and moment-countdown.min.js in my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**:

```
moment().countdown(new Date('01/19/2018 21:30'), countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES, NaN, 2).toString();
```

output

> "168 hours and 29.34 minutes"

I run this code from the console...
I include all 3 js

```
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="moment-countdown.min.js"></script>
```

maybe you can try this [moment-countdown](https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown)
examples :

```
    moment("1982-05-25").countdown().toString(); //=> '30 years, 10 months, 14 days, 1 hour, 8 minutes, and 14 seconds'

    //accepts a moment, JS Date, ISO-8601 string, or any other single arg taken my Moment's constructor
    moment("1955-08-21").countdown("1982-05-25").toString(); //=> '26 years, 9 months, and 4 days'


moment().countdown("1982-05-25", countdown.MONTHS|countdown.WEEKS, NaN, 2).toString(); //=> '370 months, and 2.01 weeks'


    //also works with the args flipped, like diff()
    moment("1982-05-25").countdown("1955-08-21").toString(); //=> '26 years, 9 months, and 4 days'
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I exactly want, however I can't get it to work
This is what I did : 
$http.get("xxx/json").then(function(response) {
   response.data.forEach( function(row, index) {
        row.MakerDueDate = moment("row.MakerDueDate").countdown().toString();
      });
    $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
  });

Unfortunately this returns : TypeError: moment(...).countdown is not a function
I included moment.js, countdown.js and moment-countdown.min.js in my html

Comment: I update my answer. I just show you how to convert date format to one that you want. see my code should work

Comment: works like charm, the issue was excelbuilder.js breaking it, so I moved it to load after moment JS and now it works

Answer (score 0):

To show only xx Hour xx minutes using moment js, the syntax would be:

```
const formattedDate = moment(date).format('hh:mm');
```

You can prepare the dates source array first, and assign to your ui grid

Comment: In the current situation and as the data set is huge creating another array doesn't seem like the best option